# CoordinatorLayout with appbar_scrolling_view_behavior causing issue with adjustResize

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-coordinatorlayout, window-soft-input-mode

I am facing weird issue with combination of `CoordinatorLayout`,`appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` and `adjustResize`.

Using this combination, I have an layout which is scrollable, when keyboard comes up and dismisses, area behind keyboard is grays out. If I set flag to `adjustPan`, this issue doesn't come up but I want to keep it as adjustResize. Below is code snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            style="@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            -----

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

It would be great if someone can give me a pointer on what exactly I am doing wrong :)

Thanks

Comment: Can you please tell me "@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutStyle" this tyle you applied to your com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout what is that ?

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?